# Angular CLI (v14/15) not generating .gitignore and .editorconfig when I use "ng new <project_name>"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am currently using Angular CLI v15.2.2 but have also tried v14.2.10 and got the same result.

When performing `ng new <project_name>` and selecting the default options for the two subsequent prompts, I get this output explicitly saying that these files (.gitignore and .editorconfig) are being created:

[image: console output of ng new test]

But when I look at the folder, I do not see these files.

I have tried switching versions but I get the same result.

[image: Actual Generated Files]

Comment: Are you 100% sure it’s not being created? I.e. are dot files just hidden from view?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this,

[How to Show Hidden Files and Folders on Your Mac](https://news.trendmicro.com/2018/03/12/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-on-your-mac/)

> **Keyboard shortcut**
> I highly recommend this way to show hidden files and folder since it is not only the easiest way, but also the quickest way.
> If you are using the macOS Sierra or a higher version, you can open your Finder, then hit “command + shift + .(dot)” on your keyboard to show hidden files/folders.
> If you hit the keyboard combination again, they will change back to original hidden status.
> However, if you are running an older version than macOS Sierra, please choose Method 2: Using Terminal to show your hidden files.